# c# system device location works off and on

Tags: c#, windows, geolocation

I have code that should work to get the location sensing, And it does work once and a while but lately without any change to the code the GeoPositionStatus is equal to NoData. Location services are on and this worked perfectly well just a few days ago and nothing has changed since. So why isn't it working now? Any advice? The computer is windows 10 and location for device is on.

```
    static GeoCoordinateWatcher _watcher;
    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Application.Run(new Form1());
        _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        _watcher.StatusChanged += Watcher_StatusChanged;
        _watcher.PositionChanged += GeoPositionChanged;

        _watcher.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        var coord = _watcher.Position.Location;
    }

    private static void Watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Watcher is ready. First location: The current location is: " +
          _watcher.Position.Location.Latitude + "/" +
          _watcher.Position.Location.Longitude + ".");
        }
    }

    private static void GeoPositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The current location is: " +
            e.Position.Location.Latitude + "/" +
            e.Position.Location.Longitude + ".");
    }
```